# Зависания программы при выгрузке DLL

Tags: delphi, dll

Нужно большой проект в Delphi разнести по dll-файлам. Но при использовании DLL часто при выгрузке dll-файлов программа зависает. Кто знает, как решить проблему?

Заметил, что чаще всего ситуация возникает при возникновении Exception в DLL, даже если это находится в блоке try.

Просьба ответы типа "Используйте .NET" не писать. И ShareMem тоже не предлагайте, специально, чтоб не использовать его, все вызовы функций из DLL организованы так, чтобы не было ни объектов VCL, ни динамических массивов.

Comment: Посмотрите отладчиком. Недаром ж он в Делфи есть =) Сколько я dll ни пользовал - просто так зависаний не встречал.

Comment: Как раз в отладчике на FreeLibrary и зависает. В Event Loge тоже последняя строка Module Unload. Т.е. такое впечатление, что система выгружает dll, но то, что оно выгружено, не сообщается exe-файлу.
То, что просто так зависаний не бывает, тут я согласен, а вот конкретную причину найти не могу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за ответы.

Пре перечисленное не помогало.
Но все исправилось (когда уже решили забить на это благо Exception возникает в dll очень редко) благодоря обновлениям виндовоза ))

Answer (score 1):

Статический импорт не выгружается. Динамический - с этим конечно будут траблы, так как вы часть приложения киляете и продолжаете его юзать :)

> система выгружает dll, но то, что оно
> выгружено, не сообщается exe-файлу.

Конечно не сообщает. Нотификация только InitRoutine(для фей DllMain) выполняется.

> конкретную причину найти не могу.

Качаете отладочные символы для основных системных модулей, и замораживаете зависший тред(в Olly). Сморите бактрейс(колстек) и определяете почему он висит и что делает, мб дедлок или есчо что. Без этой инфы вам никто не поможет, даже авторы дельфе =)

Comment: Динамический не выгружается.

Answer (score 1):

Не забывайте перед выгрузкой библиотеки удалить все связанные с ней объекты. У нас также, разнесли все по дллкам, а вот про объекты забыли, думали умрут когда надо...